# Flutter shared_preferences and image_picker Error

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

Everything is fine in the debug version, but with two problems in the release

1. Use the shared_preferences plugin in the debugging version, and the storage works normally.In the release version, if missing

   ```dart
   "SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues ({});".
   ```

   It will be displayed

   ```
   E/flutter (23058): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)
   E/flutter (23058): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156)
   E/flutter (23058): <asynchronous suspension>
   E/flutter (23058): #1      PermissionHandler.requestPermissions (package:permission_handler/src/permission_handler.dart:97)
   E/flutter (23058): <asynchronous suspension>
   E/flutter (23058): #2      LocationFlutterPlugin.requestPermission (package:flutter_bmflocation/bdmap_location_flutter_plugin.dart:85)
   E/flutter (23058): <asynchronous suspension>
   E/flutter (23058):
   E/flutter (23058): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
   ```

   If  add

   ```
   "SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues ({});"
   ```

   When the APP is off, the data is cleared and it cannot be saved,but APP works.
   I have tried adding

   ```java
   public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
   @Override
   public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
   super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
   flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new InstallAPKPlugin(this));
     }
   }
   ```

   But when I compile it:

- 

```
* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

if

```java
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
//    @Override
//    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
//        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
//        flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new InstallAPKPlugin(this));
//    }
}
```

it works

2. Debug the version of the "image_picker "plugin is working normally.

   Using this plugin in the release gets stuck and the function calls this up again

   ```
   E/flutter (22312): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)
   E/flutter (22312): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:581)
   E/flutter (22312): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158)
   E/flutter (22312): <asynchronous suspension>
   E/flutter (22312): #2      ImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker/image_picker.dart:85)
   E/flutter (22312): <asynchronous suspension>
   E/flutter (22312): #3      getImageByGallery.<anonymous closure> (package:catmap/server/GetImageByGallery.dart)
   E/flutter (22312): <asynchronous suspension>
   ```

   flutter doctor：

```
   Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
   \[√\] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows \[Version 10.0.19044.1586\], locale zh-CN)
   \[√\] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
   \[√\] Chrome - develop for the web
   \[√\] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
   \[√\] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1)
   \[√\] Connected device (3 available)

   • No issues found!
```

This is pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  html: ^0.15.0
  flutter_bmflocation: 1.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+10
  event_bus: ^2.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  flutter_drag_scale:
    git: https://github.com/LiuC520/flutter_drag_scale.git
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I guess it might be permissions issues but I can t fix it

Comment: Just stop app. Clean project using - flutter clean. Run - flutter pub get. Uninstall app from emulator/device. Build and run again.

Comment: This does not solve the problem.I try flutter build apk --profile,it works.